# What would life (some of it humanoid) be like on a planet with high amounts of silver?

Tags: planets, science-fiction

The planet I’m developing has iron in low supply but a high concentration of silver. The planet is habitable for humans and for story reasons the sentient race must be humanoid. Is it feasible for blood to be silver based?

Comment: What does "low supply" mean? Without easily accessible iron deposits, I'm afraid that any kind of technological development will be very very difficult. Human civilization really took off on the technological development path because we had access to plentiful iron deposits, enabling the production of cheap metal tools and weapons. Silver won't do as a replacement for iron, because it is extremely soft -- silver tools and weapons won't be very useful.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Sam! As-written, I'm tempted to vote to close this question as too broad. Right now it asks about both biology and technology - two huge categories in and of them selves. Would it be possible to edit the post to focus on one of these questions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no biochemist, but I don't think silver is a viable alternative to iron.
Silver is [quote](http://www.chemistryexplained.com/elements/P-T/Silver.html):

> a very inactive metal. It **does not react with oxygen** in the air under normal circumstances.

Assuming your native life breathes oxygen, silver is not a suitable replacement. Perhaps your natives breathe in sulfur compounds, which **would** be more reactive with silver - but such an environment would likely prohibit habitability for humans. Life on a human-habitable planet seems to be confined to oxygen-breathers, unless someone else can find a clever, non-toxic-to-humans, silver-compatible biology.

In the absence of iron, you could base your blood on **copper** instead. We see copper-based blood on Earth in many invertibrates, incluidng spiders, crabs, and octopuses. These creatures employ a protein called **[hemocyanin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemocyanin),** which produces very alien, blue blood.

Check out this picture of horseshoe crabs being bled, and marvel at the azure liquid oozing out. [This stuff is medically valuable](https://www.businessinsider.com/why-horseshoe-crab-blood-expensive-2018-8), so scientists harvest a lot of it.

[image]

Copper-based blood is a completely feasible replacement for iron-based blood. Imo, your biggest problem is explaining an iron-deficient planet.